# can't free double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

my problem is I have to free a double pointer. I already tried it:

```
char** files = malloc(sizeof(char*) * files_int);
for( i=1; i <= files_int ; i++)
        {
            files[i] = malloc(500);
            //fill with data...
        }
//call function with needs the double pointer
functionA(files);

//free first array
for(x=1; x <= max_files ; x++){
   free(files[x]);
   }
//free second array
free(files);
```

I am always getting a glibc detected  double free or corruption (out) error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `files[files_int]` does not exist. You are ignoring `files[0]`

Comment: You should be doing `for (int x = 0; x < max_files; x++)` with your for statements. Don't start at one because the compiler and everything else starts at 0.

Comment: You are using 1-based indices. You should use 0-based. Currently you are falling off the end of the array.

Comment: And, well, there's 3 different ways of saying the same thing within 16 seconds.

Comment: I see pointers to pointers to char.  There are no doubles and no double pointers in this program.

Comment: lol @WilliamPursell ... that's "double" as in `char ***triple` triple pointer: no need for a triple data type, but yes: it's misuse of "double"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C are `0` based:

```
for( i=1; i <= files_int ; i++)
    files[i] = malloc(500);
```

causes a buffer overflow, possibly corrupting the memory allocation system, and you do not allocate `files[0]`.